# Location of a java buffer in physical memory

Tags: java, buffer, paging, dma

I have a scenario where a **DMA capable device want to read from a buffer  created by a JAVA code**. However, the DMA device can not work unless the *physical memory address* of the java buffer is provided.

Hence, my question if there is a mechanism so that I allocate a buffer in the physical memory directly from JAVA in a way that the buffer is neither controlled by the JVM heap space nor the OS memory,  and the buffer is not subjected to virtual memory and paging. Can the java NIO 1/2 package help?

Thank you.

Comment: What?  You should be writing a driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM is a process that runs within a virtual address space that is managed by the host OS.  A typical OS does not allow a non-privileged process to control the physical memory mapping or turn off paging, etcetera.

However, a privileged process (at least on Linux) is able to access kernel memory, and map it into its own address space.  This is what `vgalib` does; see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/fake.html

Given the above, it would be possible to implement a custom memory mapped `Buffer` class that meets your requirements.  You do the work of setting up a mapped memory region in native code, and then use either native code methods or the `Unsafe` class to implement the parts of your `Buffer` class that need to access the mapped memory.

> Can the java NIO 1/2 package help?

Maybe if you use `FileChannel.map(...)` on a file handle for "/dev/kmem" ...